# powerpoint 2016 screen recording

Tags: ffmpeg, powerpoint, powerpoint-2016

Compressing an `.MP4` causes a transcoding process failure in `FFMPEG`.  The MP4 was created using the `PowerPoint 2016 Screen Recording` tool.

[image] [image]

I created an `.MP4` using the default configuration in PowerPoint 2016. When the file is compressed using `FFMPEG`, the process fails without creating a new file.

Other .MP4's work fine with `FFMPEG`.  I believe the problem is with the .mp4 generated by `PowerPoint 2016`.

Comment: Post the `ffmpeg` logs

Comment: Including your ffmpeg transcode command.